# Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly

Tags: flutter, logging, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Hello I am new to flutter and I am facing an issue for last 5-6 days

> Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped
>   unexpectedly

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                         7.3s
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Application failed to start. Will not run test. Quitting.
```

I can not run integration test Please help me resolving the issue.

MyCode : https://github.com/VickyBOSS/flutter_integration_testing

Comment: I answered a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62440700/1952331

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue as well; the app would successfully launch but would lose the connection. I was able to fix this by updating my android SDK build tools and platform tools.

You can also find some more possible solutions here if this doesn't work for you: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52764